# how to update a sqlite database schema when using schematic library?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider

I am using schematic library for creating database and content provider. Now I need to update my database schema and I haven't found any documentation that can help me with that.

I tried to follow with 
[this](https://github.com/SimonVT/schematic/issues/44) link but It doesn't help me. As I couldn't implement this. When using schamatic, we have to declare a String of table name annotated with @Table annotation and it creates the table. Now I am not sure how to create a new table on database version upgrade.